# How to create a Siri shortcut to play tunein radio on HomePod and Mac

Tags: music, automation, siri, airplay, homepod

How can I create a shortcut such that I can tell my HomePod

"Hey Siri, good morning"

and it will then play a certain tunein radio station

- on the HomePod
- and also on my Mac in the other room
- and have the playback in sync.

Currently, the only way for me is to go into the other room and start the tunein radio station on my Mac in the Music app and then select both the Mac and the HomePod as airplay output. But that's something my humble assistant should do for me … Thanks!

[image: Screenshot showing the airplay workaround]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your solution plays a list in the Music app instead of TuneIn. If you want to control TuneIn like you were originally asking, the best way I've found is to have it open in a browser and then use some JavaScript to press the right buttons. If you're using Safari, you will need to turn on **Allow JavaScript from Apple Events** in the Develop menu.

```js
    (*
    Usage: osascript <scriptname> <station>
    where <scriptname> is whatever you name the file and <station> is a
    whitespace-free part of the name of the TuneIn station on your
    Library/favorites page, unique to the station you want to choose.
    *)

    
    (*
        Get the name of the numth instance of the specified class on the specified tab
        *)
        to getInputByClass(theClass, num, tab2)
            tell application "Safari"
                set input to do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & num & "].innerHTML;" in tab2
            end tell
            return input
        end getInputByClass
    
    (*
    Click the numth instance of the specified class on the specified tab
    *)
    to clickClass(theClass, num, tab2)
        tell application "Safari"
            set input to do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & num & "].click();" in tab2
        end tell
    end clickClass
    
    (*
    Reads the specified tab looking for an element of the specified class with a particular string in its name identifier, then tries to click it
    *)
    to clickText(theClass, txt, tab2)
        set found to false
        set className to theClass
        set searchTerm to txt
        
        repeat with x from 0 to 100 -- Look through the first 100 elements of the specified class
            try
                set trialInnerHTML to getInputByClass(className, x, tab2) -- Ask for the name of the xth instance of the specified class
                
                if searchTerm is in trialInnerHTML then -- Check if the name contains the specified text
                    clickClass(className, x, tab2) -- Try to click the xth element of the specified class
                    set found to true
                    exit repeat
                end if
            end try
        end repeat
        return found
    end clickText
    
    (*
    Check if specified application is running
    *)
    to appIsRunning(appName)
        tell application "System Events" to (name of processes) contains appName
    end appIsRunning
    
    (*
        The zero_pad function taken from:
        http://www.nineboxes.net/2009/10/an-applescript-function-to-zero-pad-integers/
    *)
    on zero_pad(value, string_length)
        set string_zeroes to ""
        set digits_to_pad to string_length - (length of (value as string))
        if digits_to_pad > 0 then
            repeat digits_to_pad times
                set string_zeroes to string_zeroes & "0" as string
            end repeat
        end if
        set padded_value to string_zeroes & value as string
        return padded_value
    end zero_pad
    
    on getTimeAndDate()
        set now to (current date)
        
        set result to (year of now as integer) as string
        set result to result & "-"
        set result to result & zero_pad(month of now as integer, 2)
        set result to result & "-"
        set result to result & zero_pad(day of now as integer, 2)
        set result to result & " "
        set result to result & zero_pad(hours of now as integer, 2)
        set result to result & ":"
        set result to result & zero_pad(minutes of now as integer, 2)
        set result to result & ":"
        set result to result & zero_pad(seconds of now as integer, 2)
        
        return result as string
    end getTimeAndDate
    
    use scripting additions
    
    on run args
        
        if appIsRunning("Safari") then -- Safari startup can be messy (restoring previous windows) and the script can't deal with it: skip it and throw an error if it's not running already
            tell application "Safari"
                set searchTerm to "https://tunein.com/"
                set winlist to every window
                set break to false
                set winID to ""
                repeat with win in winlist --Look through all open windows
                    set tablist to every tab of win
                    repeat with t in tablist --Look through each tab in each window
                        if searchTerm is in (URL of t as string) then
                            set tabName to name of t
                            set tabURL to URL of t
                            (* The winID variable doesn't need all this information in the
                            current version, but it's useful for debugging *)
                            set winID to winID & ("Tab " & (index of t as integer) & " of Window " & (index of win as integer) & " has title " & tabName & " & URL " & tabURL & linefeed as string) & linefeed as string
                            set break to true
                            set xx to win
                            set yy to t
                            # If the tab we found is the TuneIn homepage (the only one with a different structure, I think) then go to the radio page before continuing
                            if tabURL = "https://tunein.com/" then
                                set URL of t to "https://tunein.com/radio/home/"
                            end if
                            exit repeat
                        end if
                    end repeat
                    if break then
                        exit repeat
                    end if
                end repeat
                if winID = "" then --If no tab was already on TuneIn, open a new window on the radio homepage
                    make new document with properties {URL:"https://tunein.com/radio/home/"}
                end if
            end tell
            
            #       display dialog winID buttons "OK" --helps with debugging
            
            #       set docText to winID & " " & xx & " " & yy & linefeed as string --helps with debugging
            
            # Find and click the Library button
            clickText("leftSide-module__navigationMenuItem___snR6K common-module__link___Mz1h3", "Library", yy)
            
            # Deals with an issue with a space in the name of one station
            if (item 1 of args) = "WAMC-HD2" then
                set station to "WAMC 2"
            else
                set station to item 1 of args
            end if
            
            # Try to press the button 60 times, in case the page takes time to load
            repeat with x from 1 to 60
                set r to clickText("guide-item-module__guideItemPlayButtonContainer___q7_TL guide-item-module__guideItemLink___HP1Vy common-module__link___Mz1h3", station, yy)
                if r then
                    exit repeat
                else if r is false and x = 60 then --Show an error if the specified station can't be found
                    set errText to "Could not change TuneIn station."
                    set dialDisplay to "Could not find specified station." & linefeed & getTimeAndDate() & linefeed & "Arguments:" & linefeed
                    repeat with i from 1 to length of args
                        set dialDisplay to dialDisplay & (item i of args as string) & " "
                    end repeat
                    display alert errText message dialDisplay buttons {"OK"}
                end if
            end repeat
        else --Show an error if Safari is not open
            set errText to "Could not change TuneIn station"
            set dialDisplay to "Safari is not open." & linefeed & getTimeAndDate() & linefeed & "Arguments:" & linefeed
            repeat with i from 1 to length of args
                set dialDisplay to dialDisplay & (item i of args as string) & " "
            end repeat
            display alert errText message dialDisplay buttons {"OK"}
        end if
    end run
```

I use a similar SSH shortcut setup as yours to run it from my phone, but with a menu to select the station I want to play. I can share this as well if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, I'm just missing the obvious solution. But for now, this is working for me:

#### Summary

A Siri shortcut executes an Apple Script on the Mac that starts the radio stream with the Music app and adds the HomePod as airplay output.

#### 1. Apple Script to start the radio stream

On the Mac, create a script using the `Script Editor` application and save it e.g. to `~/play-radio.scpt`.

```
# ~/play-radio.scpt
tell application "Music"
    set selected of AirPlay device "HomePod Kitchen" to true
    set selected of AirPlay device "HomePod Living-Room" to true
    play (every track of playlist "My Radio Playlist")
end tell
```

In the Playlist "My Radio Playlist", I've added the radio stream I want to start. I suppose, one could also add the radio stream's url directly. But this way, I can modify the playlist without re-opening the script again later.

#### 2. Create Shortcut to execute the script

With the device that has been paired with the HomePod, e.g. the iPhone or iPad, open the `Shortcuts` app and create a new shortcut that is named after the desired Siri command, here: "good morning"

[image: good-morning workflow]

Add the workflow item **Run Script Over SSH**. Enter the hostname of the Mac and your Mac's user-account name. Choose "SSH Key" as authentication method. Add the command to execute the apple script:

```
osascript ~/play-radio.scpt
```

#### 3. Import the SSH Key

If you haven't done so already, export the public SSH Key of the Shortcuts app by clicking on the SSH Key entry, share, and then air-drop it onto your Mac.

On the Mac, add the key to the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

**Attention!** This will allow the Shortcuts app on your iOS device to ssh into your Mac.

#### 4. Activate SSH

If you haven't done so already, activate SSH remote login on your Mac:

- Go to "System Preferences"
- Go to "Sharing"
- Activate "Remote login"

Now the HomePod will understand "good morning" and execute the script, which will start Music on the Mac playing the radio station on the Mac and the selected AirPlay devices.